# how to join two arrays in js to get an new array with both its values

Tags: javascript

consider this two arrays array y and array x i need to concatenates  them but not after each other but be organised as in the form of array k
the concatenate method just output them after each other

```
let x=['name','age','id'];
let y=['kyle',50,5050];
let k= x.concat(y);
```

the output i get is

```
k=['name','age','id','kyle',50,5050]
```

so how to merge them to get this output array

```
let k=['name':'kyle','age':50,'id':5050]
```

Comment: What you want is *not* a valid array, you probably want an object.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries

Comment: @SSM it is a valid array, just not recommended (and you can't declare it using an array literal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the javascript array doesn't look like this. We can have an array of objects or array of arrays

```
let keys=['name','age','id'];
let values=['kyle',50,5050];

var array = keys.map((el, i) => {
  return {[keys[i]]:values[i]}
}); // as array of objects

var array = keys.map((el, i) => {
  return [keys[i], values[i]];
}); // as array of arrays
```

of if you want a single object you can use

```
let obj = {};
keys.forEach((element, index) => {
  obj[element] = values[index];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but not as an array. You need an object.

```js
const x = ['name', 'age', 'id'];
const y = ['kyle', 50, '5050'];

const k = {};

x.forEach((element, index) => {
  k[element] = y[index];
});

console.log(k);
```

Comment: Actually you can use an array, but it will not function in expected ways.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you
Note: `k` is not an `array`, it's an `object` [read about JavaScript object here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

```js
    let x = ['name', 'age', 'id'];
    let y = ['kyle', 50, 5050];
    let k = {};
    x.forEach((item, index) => {
        k[item] = y[index];
    });
   console.log(k);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
let x = ['name', 'age', 'id'];
let y = ['kyle', 50, 5050];
k= x.map((prop, i) => [prop, y[i]]);
console.log(k);// [["name","kyle"],["age",50],["id",5050]]
```